# launchctl not setting environment variables in yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I have wasted most of the day trying to get some simple environment variables set that will be visible to GUI apps along with shell variables. I have tried virtually everything I've found on the web, but I can get a variable set with launchctl to visible in bash. I have a script that runs as a login item that does a simple `launchctl setenv FOO BAR`. When I type `launchctl getenv FOO` it returns `BAR`. If I type `echo $FOO` I get an empty string. I can't believe apple would something this simple so hard. I must be missing something. Am I?

Comment: `killall Dock` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `launchctl setenv FOO BAR` in Terminal you are setting the variable in `launchd` environment. You will have to restart Terminal (all its processes) to see the change. `launchd` will pass your new variable while starting Terminal and it will be visible in it's new instance running `echo $FOO`. The same applies to all applications.

Comment: That's what I was expecting to happen but it doesn't. If I set the variable in a terminal window, close the window and open a new terminal, 'echo $FOO' still returns an empty string. I've even got a small application I created with script editor that is run at startup setting the variable. Same result, always empty from bash command line. Been pulling my hair out for most of the day trying figure out why....

Comment: I just tried it and it works here. Be sure to close the whole app, not only window.

Comment: My bad. I was only closing the window and not the entire app. :( Works like a charm now. THANKS!

Comment: Just a FYI. On macOS Monterey, I just tried by running the command `launchctl setenv FOO BAR2` but when I try to echo it with `echo $FOO`, nothing shows up. Regardless if I try to echo in the same terminal or a new terminal.